# Ajax : Unable to fetch array from webservice (.asmx) (Error: TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, xml, web-services

I want to fetch data from web service which hosted on server (ASP.net web service).
Here is my Ajax Code to fetch data. It fetch data successfully but when I pass that through loop, its display an error **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a**.

**Ajax Code**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://demo.demoname.com/MyService.asmx/UserDetails',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'xml',
  success: function(data) {
    var jsonArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data.activeElement.innerHTML))
    console.log(jsonArray);
    $.each( jsonArray, function( intValue, currentElement ) {
        // Do work with currentElement
        console.log(currentElement );       
    });

  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    //console.log(e.message);
  }
});
</script>
```

This code return following output of **console.log(jsonArray);**

```
[{"Name":"Patna Chilli Pawder","Sku":"250gm","Price":300},{"Name":"Turmeric Powder","Sku":"750gm","Price":400}]
```

But when loop invoke, its display **TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a**

**Other useful info**

- Responce

> [{"Name":"Patna Chilli Pawder","Sku":"250gm","Price":300},{"Name"
>   :"Turmeric Powder","Sku":"750gm","Price":400}]

- XML

> [{"Name":"Patna Chilli Pawder","Sku":"250gm","Price":300},{"Name":"Turmeric Powder","Sku":"750gm","Price":400}]

**Please note that I try to get data from my localhost by setup virtual host in WAMP**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is usually a sign that you're trying to iterate over a string. That said, because you're receiving XML with a value of a JSON string, you don't have to use JSON.stringify, and you can just use JSON.parse to convert the string into an object. Here's how you'd access the data given your circumstances.

```
success: function(data) {
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(data.activeElement.innerHTML);
    $.each( dataArray, function( index, property ) {
        // Do work with currentElement
        console.log( property );     
    });
},
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Message : response isn't an array

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` and see what it outputs, just so I can get an idea of the actual response you're getting.

Comment: same, response isn't an array

Comment: you can see firebug's value in XML and responce in my question

Comment: Do you have control over the response? Like, can you simply output the JSON instead of outputting the JSON string inside of an XML tag? If you're building an API that provides a JSON response, you shouldn't then enclose that in an XML tag.. Just dump the JSON straight to the document and then change the `dataType` setting in the `$.ajax()` call to be `json`, and you can handle the data like I do it my answer above.

Comment: Np, right now i do not have control, but if you give me resource (link) for how to create one, I can setup in my local

Comment: I'm not an ASP.net guy, so rather than do that, I'll adjust my response to accommodate the XML. See my modified answer above.

Comment: Yes, Yes. Many many thanks. Its work perfectly. you made my day. really appreciate your hard work :)